# WPF Path Geometry; drawing a box with a centred arrow on the top

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, pathgeometry

I am trying to draw a simple box with an "arrow head" centred at the top, but I do not seem to be able to get that arrow head to centre (as shown in the following example, the arrow heads are always offset to the left)...

[image: An example of what I have so far]

Here is my XAML (this is actually inside a template but I do not think that is the problem)...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="16" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            Data="M -8,0 L 0,-16 8,0" />
</Grid>
```

The "Content" for the ContentPresenter is a StackPanel that may or may not have TextBlock children.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `Stretch` is `None`, the Path's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` (and hence its alignment) doesn't take into account the parts of its geometry that are drawn at negative coordinates.

Change it to

```
<Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0,0 L 8,-16 16,0" ... />
```

or

```
<Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="M -8,0 L 0,-16 8,0"
      Stretch="Uniform" Width="16" Height="16" ... />
```

Comment: I guess I get to thank you again; really appreciated - I don't need to tell you it works of course!